# How to generate offline swagger doc with beego

Tags: go, swagger, beego

I'm developing a website with beego and I want to generate docs with swagger.

The official doc of beego showed us how to generate doc with swagger: https://beego.me/docs/advantage/docs.md

I've succeeded in generating swagger doc following the doc above.

However, the doc is not offline, meaning that I have to keep the server of my website running to use the online doc.

Is it possible to generate a kind of offline doc?

Comment: I am a beego beginner. Once the swagger is generated, there is an index.html file in the swagger folder. Opening it we go against the "CORS request not HTTP" problem. Using firefox we can disable this option in "about: config" and setting privacy.file_unique_origin (insecure) to false. https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp

Comment: Do you need an offline dynamic swagger or just as documentation would you also be fine static?

Comment: @AndreaManzi  I simply need that I can send the generated doc to anyone, and they can read the doc without Internet.

Answer (score 0):

To generate offline swagger i start local server (ex. localhost:8088/swagger/) and run

```
docker run -e "JAVA_MEM=1024m" -e "HTTP_PORT=80" -p 8888:80 --name swagger-generator-v3 -v /tmp:/jetty_home/lib/shared swaggerapi/swagger-generator-v3
```

When swagger generator is on: `http://localhost:8888/index.html`

Using "POST" /generate route with parameters ("lang": "html" or "lang": "html2")

```
{
    "lang": "html",
    "specURL": "http://172.17.0.1:8088/swagger/swagger.json"
}
```

click "execute" and get "download file"

Or using this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTFILE="offline_swagger.zip"
HOST=127.0.0.1
SWAGGER_IP_PORT=8090

DOCKER_IP=$(ip addr show | grep "\binet\b.*\bdocker0\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 1)
SWAGGERJSON=http://$DOCKER_IP:$SWAGGER_IP_PORT/swagger/swagger.json
API_URL="http://$HOST:8888/api/generate"

generate_post_data()
{
  cat <<EOF
{
    "lang": "html",
    "specURL": "$SWAGGERJSON"
}
EOF
}
#Check if swagger is on
</dev/tcp/$HOST/$SWAGGER_IP_PORT
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Connection to $HOST on port $SWAGGER_IP_PORT failed"
  exit 1
fi
docker run -d -e "JAVA_MEM=1024m" -e "HTTP_PORT=80" -p 8888:80 -v /tmp:/jetty_home/lib/shared swaggerapi/swagger-generator-v3
sleep 10
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'accept: application/json' --data "$(generate_post_data)"  ${API_URL} -o $OUTFILE
docker stop $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor=swaggerapi/swagger-generator-v3 )
echo "Output to $OUTFILE"
```